# A word describes the person whose homeland/origins cannot be assurely identified

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking for adjective describes the person whose origins cannot be identified based on his appearance features, accent, background ... etc. Some people has typical appearance features of middle Africans, Scandinavian, Chinese, Latin and so forth. I am aware that there is no strict line defines whether persons is coming from this area or that (e.g. a Scandinavian looking could be from USA). But generally speaking, if you met someone and you could not locate his/her origins due to overlapping and confusing features, what word can describe that person? I am looking for something more specific than (mixed).

Comment: Generic seems appropriate.

Comment: ‘Normal’. There are very, very few people that you can reliably nation based on their looks alone—more and more so, with the ever-increasing mobility of people all over the world.

Comment: 'of unknown origin'

Comment: More specific than "mixed" is "mongrel", which is very offensive when applied to people. I'd actually suggest going less specific with something like "indeterminate".

Comment: There are lots of ways this could go; is it the perceiver's difficulty? Have they never seen that type before? Does the person have features that are typical of more than one type? . In addition to others: non-descript, unidentifiable, of unknown origin, mixed-race.

Comment: unidentifiable ethnicity

Comment: Personally, I find this entire question icky. You could perhaps identify a large group of people's joint nationality by sight, but a single individual? No way. Statistically impossible. If there is a word for attempting to do so anyway, **you shouldn't be using it**.

Comment: ...and this is a pointless exercise in any English-speaking country. I can't think of a single one that is racially homogeneous. Its *accent* that lets you place a person, not looks.

Comment: what about 'caucasian'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the U.S., where historically race was a more important social distinction than ethnicity or class (or, given the [hypodescent](http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2010/12/101209074405.htm) standard, even skin color), people who are ***racially ambiguous*** are a subject of interest, both in popular (“10 most racially ambiguous celebrities!”) and intellectual (*[“What Are You?”: Racial Ambiguity and the Social Construction of Race in the US](http://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc115163/)*) sources.

By extension, *ethnically ambiguous* would be a broader application of the concept, and to my surprise, turns up almost the same number of Google.com results. A 2003 [*New York Times* article](http://www.nytimes.com/2003/12/28/style/generation-ea-ethnically-ambiguous.html) suggests

> ethnically neutral, diverse or ambiguous

I think few people would self-identify as "ambiguous" alone as a description of phenotype, or if they do it would be interpreted as *[androgynous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/androgynous)*. Rather, this is a label others apply. People who know they are of mixed descent could self-identify as *[multiracial](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126099)* (U.S. Census category), *mixed race*, or *multiethnic*— but in a modern professional setting in the U.S., calling attention to such characteristics is usually inappropriate and even outré.

For similar reasons, terms like *mulatto* or *quadroon* are considered outdated, and may be taken to be offensive.

Answer (score 3):

- There is this tailor shop at the edge of Manhattan where I met its owner of **indiscernible racial** origins. Was he from Bulgaria, Turkey, Turkmenistan, China or Afghanistan? I could hardly tell.
- I came upon a lonely night, at a place far from the vicissitudes of human kindness and cruelty, when I encountered a being of **indiscernible origin**, and indiscernible horror-movie taxonomy, whose constant vicissitude in behaviour made it impossible to tell if he was vampire, werewolf, frankensteinian, angel, devil or polydemiglot (being conversant in various angelic/demonic tongues).
- According to our holy book of sacred witchery, one of the seven spiritual gifts is **discernment**. In fact, we hold that discernment is the most supreme of all gifts. For it gives the giftee the ability to discern the various species of spirits and their hidden intents, and  thus allowing the holder of the gift, the giftee, the ability to sway and exploit the **indiscernible** confusion the spirits cast upon each other.

> [in·dis·cern·i·ble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indiscernible)
>   adj.
>   Difficult or impossible to discern or perceive; imperceptible: an indiscernible increase in temperature.
>   in′dis·cern′i·bly adv.
>
> *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*

Comment: The first bullet makes sense. The second and third are weird. What are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

Consider *nontypical*, *[untypical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/untypical?q=untypical)*, and the likely less offensive [*non-stereotypical*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/non-stereotypical).

> [untypical](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/untypical): not representative of a particular type, person, etc.
>
> [nontypical](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/non-typical): not having the distinctive qualities of a particular type of person or thing; uncharacteristic
>
> **type**: qualities common to a number of individuals that distinguish them as an identifiable class, as the morphological, physiological, or ecological characters by which relationship between organisms may be recognized.

That being said, what I would typically say of that person is that they are of [unidentifiable origin](http://www.inter-relations.org/college.htm).

Comment: Somehow this sounds less offensive than featureless.

Comment: Perhaps even [unstereotypical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unstereotypical), which would be even less likely to cause offence.

Comment: 'Atypical' is the preferred word.

Comment: @Mitch I think "untypical" sounds more explicit than "atypical" in relation to human types.

Comment: If 'untypical' is a word at all (it sounds like a malformation of 'atypical', like 'unflammable'), then it means 'not typical' or out of the ordinary, as opposed to non-descript or unidentifiable.

Comment: @Mitch Actually, "atypical" sounds more like "uncommon," "singular," or "unusual" to my ear. For instance, I would sat that former French President Nicolas Sarkozy is an atypical Frenchman, not specifically because of his physical appearance, but because he is the son of a Hungarian father and a mother who was herself the daughter of a Greek immigrant.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't agree. Saying that someone is the French type and that they embody the French stereotype doesn't mean the same.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet https://www.google.com.br/search?client=safari&hl=pt-BR&biw=768&bih=928&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=t0KHU-rgDKjM0AXx0oCgAw&q=french+stereotype&oq=french+stere&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.0.0.206884.214647.0.216601.23.20.0.3.3.5.342.3111.3j10j3j2.18.0....0...1c.1.45.tablet-gws..9.14.1888.gX6HNPvPEs0#facrc=_&imgrc=BPrwrOxs-J3hpM%253A%3BY4O4tYPSjSLUxM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fimg3.wikia.nocookie.net%252F__cb20110120224447%252Funcyclopedia%252Fimages%252F1%252F1a%252FFrench-stereotype.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Funcyclopedia.wikia.com%252Fwiki%252FFile%253AFrench-stereotype.jpg%3B300%3B372

Comment: _Unstereotypical_ would in this context refer to someone not having the stereotypical features of wherever they’re from, rather than them not acting like a stereotype (which is really more of a caricature) of their countrymen.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Okay. I just added it to my answer.

Comment: Atypical or (untypical or unstereotypical) means 'different from the usual'. The OP is looking for 'difficult to identify' which is a very different concept. Someone who is atypical may be very easy to identify.

Answer (score 1):

*[featureless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/featureless)*

> adj.
>   Lacking distinguishing characteristics or features
>   "her face was as round and red as a harvest-moon and almost as featureless." – *Anne of The Island* by Lucy Maud Montgomery.

syn: *uncharacterized*

Comment: Very neutral, but not specifically for racial distinctions. It can also be interpreted as *plain*. If I were told a woman were featureless I would think that they mean to tell me that she is neither pretty nor ugly, plain. I +1 for uncharacterized, though.

Comment: @fredsbend True, featureless=plain, it's that plain & simple. However, the word is preferred precisely for being "very neutral" and also not immediately evoking images of race/region. PC! With regular & frequent use it can (has to some extent did) acquire an idiomatic sense.

Answer (score 0):

I am a mix of several national origins.  I would describe myself as a **mutt**.  Often when I travel abroad people have no idea where I am from, but they know I am not from there.  The term mutt is good.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word ***ambiguous***.

You could say:

- His racial origins are ambiguous.
- His face is racially ambiguous.
- He belongs to some ambiguous race (or ambiguous racial combination).
- Any determination of his race would be ambiguous without asking.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?